# Generic SQL Query with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

[**Please click here for sample tables and description**.](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=587&d=1336661439)

I have two tables ‘VEHICLE’ and ‘VEHICLE_CLASS’ as per attached images.

I need a query to get the result rows with how many VEHICLES each VEHICLE_CLASS has grouped by status as shown in attached image.

The query should be generic so that it can be used in any database (MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL/DB2)

Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE 
(
    VEHICLE_ID varchar(20), 
    VEHICLE_CLASS_ID varchar(30),
    STATUS int
);

CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_CLASS
(
    VEHICLE_CLASS_ID varchar(30),
    VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME varchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO VEHICLE
   (VEHICLE_ID, VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, STATUS)
VALUES
   ('vehicle_001', 'vehicle_class_001', 0),
   ('vehicle_002', 'vehicle_class_002', 1),
   ('vehicle_003', 'vehicle_class_003', 2),
   ('vehicle_004', 'vehicle_class_001', 0),
   ('vehicle_005', 'vehicle_class_002', 2),
   ('vehicle_006', 'vehicle_class_001', 0),
   ('vehicle_007', NULL, 1);


INSERT INTO VEHICLE_CLASS
   (VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME)
VALUES
   ('vehicle_class_001', 'ABC'),
   ('vehicle_class_002', 'BCD'),
   ('vehicle_class_003', 'EFG');
```

Here is the query that I tried but didn't able to get desired result:

```
SELECT veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN veh.STATUS=2 THEN COUNT(veh.VEHICLE_ID) end) Completed,
    SUM( CASE WHEN veh.STATUS!=2 THEN COUNT(veh.VEHICLE_ID) end) not_completed
FROM VEHICLE veh LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass on veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
    GROUP BY veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID having veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID is not null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where pretty close. Instead of  `SUM( CASE WHEN veh.STATUS=2 THEN COUNT(veh.VEHICLE_ID)` its, then 1 and also you need to group by VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME (except in MySQL but you wanted it to work in the others).

```
SELECT veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, 
       vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN veh.STATUS = 2 THEN 1 
           END) Completed, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN veh.STATUS <> 2 THEN 1 
           END) not_completed 
FROM   VEHICLE veh 
       LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass 
         ON veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID 
GROUP  BY veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, 
          vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME 
HAVING veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

[DEMO SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c175a/6)

[DEMO MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c175a/2)

[DEMO Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b66b1/2)

**Notes**

- As Lamak pointed out `<>` is typically used but it seems `!=` to be well supported but you'll need to test
- I didn't add `Else 0` Because the image included a blank space in the SUM_not_completed. You may choose to do this or add a `COALACE` if you do want zeros
- If you know you're in MySQL you can remove the `CASE` and do `Sum(veh.STATUS = 2) Completed`

Comment: +1, you beat me to the answer. The only change I would make (and I did on my answer) is to replace the `!=` with `<>` so it works on different RDBMs

Comment: @Lamak That's weird. I always write `<>` but it worked on SQL Server Oracle and MySQL.

Comment: Really?, I knew that `!=` worked on SQL, and I thought I was kinda sure that it didn't on MySQL, maybe they added it on more recent versions. Good to know!, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, 
        vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN veh.STATUS = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
        SUM(CASE WHEN veh.STATUS <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) not_completed
FROM VEHICLE veh 
LEFT JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass 
ON veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
WHERE veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    VEHICLE_CLASS.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            VEHICLE
        WHERE
            VEHICLE.STATUS=2
            AND VEHICLE.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID=VEHICLE_CLASS.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
    ) AS SUM_Completed,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            VEHICLE
        WHERE
            VEHICLE.STATUS IN (1,0)
            AND VEHICLE.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID=VEHICLE_CLASS.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
    ) AS SUM_Not_Completed
FROM
    VEHICLE_CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME,
    SUM(case when veh.status = 2 then 1 end) Completed,
    SUM(case when veh.status != 2 then 1 end) not_completed
from VEHICLE veh
left join VEHICLE_CLASS vehclass on veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = vehclass.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
where veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID is not null
group by veh.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VC.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, VC.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN V.STATUS=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Completed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V.STATUS!=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) not_completed
FROM VEHICLE V
    JOIN VEHICLE_CLASS VC on V.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID = VC.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID
GROUP BY VC.VEHICLE_CLASS_ID, VC.VEHICLE_CLASS_NAME
```